# Replacing parts of inqueality in context of big o notation

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

I am preparing for my exam in *algorithm & data structures* by working myself through some assignments handed out by our professor.

One of the assignments and its solution in particular confuse me.

The assignment is to prove, that $U(n) = \mathcal{O}{(4^n)}$, where
$$
U(n) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if 1 $\leq$ n $\leq$ 2} \\
U(n-2) + 2U(n-1) + 1 & \text{if n > 2}
\end{cases}
$$

By using the definition for $\mathcal{O}$, I figured out, that I had to proof that:
$$
U(n) \leq 4^n 
$$

Inserting the definition of $U$, I get stuck here:
$$
\begin{align}
U(n) & \leq U(n-2) + 2 * U(n-1) + 1 \\
     & \leq 4^{n-2} + 2 * 4^{n-1} + 1
\end{align}
$$

At this point I am stuck; the proposed solution, however, goes further:
$$
\begin{align}
U(n) & \leq \ldots \\
     & \leq 4^{n-2} + 2 * 4^{n-1} + 1 \tag{1}\label{1}\\
     & \leq 4^{n-1} + 2 * 4^{n-1} + 4^{n-1} \tag{2}\label{2}\\ 
     & \leq 4*4^{n-1} = 4^n. \
\end{align}
$$

Why am I allowed to simply replace the addends $4^{n-2}$ and $1$ from equation $\ref{1}$ simply with $4^{n-1}$ resulting in equation $\ref{2}$?

What is the general rule behind it? Can I replace any addend with a bigger addend in this class of proofs?

Comment: You can look up **Introduction to algorithms by J.H.Cormen, MIT press**

Comment: Welcome to MSE! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @evaristegd I am aware, that I should mark the question as answered. However, as a new contributor to this subforum, I am supposed to wait for a specific time (I think it is 24h?)  until I am able to do it. Thanks for the reminder though :)

Comment: Got it, sorry if my comment was too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n\geq 1,$ it's obvious that $1\leq 4^{n-1}.$ Also, $$4^{n-2}\leq 4^{n-1}$$ for any $n$. So, they just bounded the terms in (1) by the above in order to combine everything together to get $4^n$, like you wanted. Since the inequalities hold, doing this process is valid (to answer your final question). Just be careful that you don't get overzealous and bound by something too large!

Comment: So, I can replace anything as long as its guaranteed that it's smaller smaller than what I am replacing it with?

Comment: Exactly. If I have some inequality $\cdots \leq a+b,$ and I know that $a\leq c,$ then I can write $\cdots\leq a+b\leq b+c.$

Comment: Alright, I guess, I understood that. Can I do that within any inequality or only those using the big-o notation? Also, how does this not divert the proof?

Comment: I mean, it's mathematically valid to do whenever, since the inequality is true; it depends on what you're trying to show and if it says anything meaningful.

Comment: I totally forgot about $\leq$'s property of transitivity. Now everything makes sense, of course. Thanks for the explanations :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped!